# Is secure to let access to ip-based blocked website to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: security, ip, localhost

I have a website that should not be visible for people outside some countries.

I do a ip-blocking, but for testing purposes I need to let 127.0.0.1 access to the website. I know that ip blocking isn't totally safe, but, letting 127.0.0.1 access, can create troubles?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, have I answered your question or would you like further explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is simply your localhost. Allowing this IP simply says that you allow *this* machine (and only this if `127.0.0.1` is the only IP you whitelisted) to access the Network so no, there wouldn't be any issue with allowing access to your localhost so long as that machine itself isn't compromised. Note: loopback address is not publicly-facing but are re-routed by the machine's network adapter.

Resources:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)
- [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/126304/why-is-the-localhost-ip-127.0.0.1/)